# API is not working in IE11 by using AJAX, .html page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, api

```
$.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
        contentType: "application/json",
        datatype: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger
            if (data) {
                 console.log('true');
             }
             else {
                 console.log('false');
             }
         },
         error: function (status, err) {
              debugger
              console.log(status);
         }
    });
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BXUu.png)

When I am calling API,the ajax call doesn't succeed but throws error.
Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: `$.support.cors` is a variable telling you if the browser supports CORS. It is utterly pointless trying to change it. That will only break code which needs to know if the browser supports CORS or not.

Comment: @Quentin When am removing $.support, cors, I got "No Transport" error

Comment: @Quentin Actual api i called is 
https://crmwebapi.ncigroupws.com/api/Customer/101

Answer (score 0):

Does you API support cors?. If not you need to install that package and than in you API and then need to set this in startup class.

```
   public class Startup
    {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
         app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
       }

    }
```

Comment: It's just a Html form, i need to call api in onchange event of a textbox